# How to add view link in datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

Hi
 I am using datagridview in window form. Issue is that it is not showing large amount of data. I have field of comment in database when user put large text datagridview give exception and doesn't appear. and give exception  Constraint Exception was unhandled
 Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I would like to show only name of user and by clicking on it its remaning detail open in message box. I have used hyperlinks in datagridview in asp.net but here way of using grid is different. I am new to csharp. so don't have any idea to implement this.
any help?

With regards
           Touseef

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataGridView [DataGridViewLinkColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx).

See also [Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx)

Comment: is there any way to make grid column like link onclicking its popup the information of particular field.. suppose I have column of of user name,, by clicking on username it popup a window which have remaining info of user? I have idea of datagridview in asp web app. but I am using grid in window application.

Comment: @Touseef You can use the DGV's CellContentClicked event's ColumnIndex property to see if your user name column was clicked.  If it was you can use the event's RowIndex property access the same row on the other columns in the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `MaxLength` property of the TextBox control in your grid view. Set `myTextBox.MaxLength =`  to the number of chars this field is allowed in your database.

Comment: is there any way to make grid column like link onclicking its popup the information of particular field.. suppose I have column of of user name,, by clicking on username it popup a window which have remaining info of user? I have idea of datagridview in asp web app. but I am using grid in window application.